# Android SDK and AVD Manager where is Settings menu?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am dealing with a problem discussed on many forums but they all say go to the "settings" menu on the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" screen.  Yet I have installed in on multiple machines and do not see a Settings menu.   Where is the menu?   I have it installed on Windows XP and Vista.

Thanx
Julian

Comment: true you will only get the settings menu if you run it manually. you will right click left corner to get it if i remember right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It only appears when I run it manually.

On a Mac, it is located in:

```
/android/tools/android
```

On Ubuntu:

```
android-sdk-linux/tools/android
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright the trick is you have to run it manually, if you run it from Eclipse it does not show the settings item.   Its in the main folder called SDK Setup.exe.

Answer (score 4):

I found that, at least on OSX 10.9, when this happens, I can get the menu to appear by hiding (Command-H), then re-showing the SDK/AVD manager. This seems to be a new problem with Mavericks. Another solution is to run "android sdk" using sudo, but that changes the cache path and uses different settings than a normal user.

Comment: +1 Hide/show works. This was driving me absolutely nuts, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a list box on the left hand side of the main window.  One of the items in that box is "Settings."  It isn't really a menu.  It has proxy server settings and a decryption checkbox.

Comment: But I do not have one.  I have seen it on screenshots but it is not on mine.  How do I get this checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

in my Ubuntu 13.10 system using Android ADK, I had to run the android app with sudo.
I would imagine this could be the solution for some people.
For example,

```
sudo ~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/android
```

Then (AND ONLY THEN) am I seeing the "settings" on the application menu bar that I would expect to see (and is described in the docs). 
So the gist, ... sudo is the key.
then of course, set your proxy settings.