# Set Android SDK behind server proxy?

Tags: android, proxy

How can I download android sdk package behind a server proxy?

Comment: removed salutation: ", thanks in advance.", don't do it next time

Comment: If you set a system wide proxy, you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image: Select Option]

[image: Edit your Proxy Settings Appropriately be setting it as show below]

you can see the proxy setting from IE if you are using windows for linux it is different

Comment: Yes right, it right there, I did not notice that :)

Comment: And if proxy wants username and password❓

Comment: The proxy settings are already set elsewhere,that includes the username and the password.You have to manually configure the proxy settings for your organization.The sdk manager will ask for the username and password and you have to enter them.

Comment: After exit, I need to re-configure it. This configuration not saved in my MacOS machine.

Comment: @deostroll if proxy asks for username and password,just set them

Answer (score 23):

On Linux or OSX create or edit the ~/.android/androidtool.cfg file.
Add the following settings with your proxy server details:

```
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
http.proxyPort=8080
```

After you've added the settings start `<sdk root>/tools/android sdk`

The SDK manager will ask for your proxy userId / password.

Comment: Same method can be applied to Windows machines. Look for the files in %USERPROFILE%\.android\androidtool.cfg

Comment: Excellent! Works! Also for set `force http...` you need to set this: `sdkman.force.http=true`.

Answer (score 5):

The SDK downloader does have proxy settings. You can go to Tools > Options to find the settings with ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the SDK manager manually, rather than from Eclipse, there is a Settings menu which contains proxy options. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2204065/385478

Comment: run <path-to-android-sdk>/tools/android

Comment: That's what i have by doing that [link](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-f2qJ6xk4qMw/T3r3EZUtHSI/AAAAAAAAADk/iDQirN_t5KU/s1529/Capture.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Installation of android SDK (**on windows 7 with proxy authetication**)

Steps: [How to set proxy for android sdk manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296708/how-to-set-proxy-for-android-sdk-manager/51973575#51973575)