# Android IDE set up

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt, android-sdk-tools

when I try to view website for the first time in a day using web browser, it redirects to corporate's proxy SSO login, and after logging in I am able to view all websites normally. In Eclipse I have set the network connection settings ***Active Provider*** to Native, and the install new software is able to retrieve update sites and working properly.But When I launch the SDK manager from eclipse it is not able to find the host of repository. getting the following errors:

**Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**

**Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**

I dont know the proxy details as it is set by some script in corporate environment.

I am able to view the repository-10.xml in browser and have managed to download the archive files for platform, system image.

when launched independently the emulator shows no errors but when i try to launch a specific avd configuration the program doesnt respond and terminates.

through eclipse the emulator is showing the following error:

[image: Emulator Error]
Is it possible to configure android sdk with eclipse just downloading required files manually or it should be downloaded only through sdk manager?

how to make sdk manager to pick the internet connection that eclipse is already able to pick it...?

I am using adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 SDK bundle,
android-19_r03 in platforms folder,
having sys images in multiple places both zipped and unzipped. dont know exactly where to have it.

**UPDATE:**

Somehow managed to get the proxy details that I should be using in my network. and setting up the proxy details in SDK Manager tools resolved the issue of connecting SDK Manager to repository. but still need to make the environment up and running. The SDK Manager connects and lists all the packages available for installation. but i am not able to see system images in that list. in repository-10.xml system images details are available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993690/set-android-sdk-behind-server-proxy

Comment: @AlexFarber but i mentioned that i dont know proxy details and its set by some configuration script. IE options doesn't show it.