# How to download and add v7-appcompat library manually without SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I checked this link to:

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

It says I should use SDK manager to download and add  v7-appcompat, however I have to connect to internet through proxy and when I use SDK manager it cannot download anything.

So how can I download and add v7-appcompat?

I KNOW HOW TO USE PROXY, BUT PROXY MAKE MY INTERNET SPEED WORSE, SO SKD MANAGER GET TIMED OUT MESSAGE.

(I want to use material design, but when I use this theme: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar it connot resolve it, I checked through web and I find out I need to add v7-appcompat and there is not any folder like extras\android\support)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set Android SDK behind server proxy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993690/set-android-sdk-behind-server-proxy)

Comment: I know how to use proxy, however when I use it SDK cannot download anything because of time out. My bandwidth is awful and proxy make it worse.

Comment: Okay then. I found this after 5 min of search: https://github.com/koush/android-support-v7-appcompat/tree/master/libs

Comment: Also, Android is an open source project, so if you feel brave enough you can download source code and build it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Manual download steps:

- Run SDK manager at least once after installation, so it would create its config folder.
- Find `.android` folder in your home folder (`~` on *nix, `C:\Users\<username>` on Windows)
- Open `sites-settings.cfg`
- Pick a repository string that will likely contain your package (repo names after `=` sign could give you a clue). In your case it will be:

  ```
  @name@https\://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml=Google Inc.
  ```
- Paste picked URL into a browser address bar:

  ```
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon-6.xml
  ```
- You will see an XML file that describes downloads available in the  repository. We are interested in:

  ```
  <sdk:name-display>Android Support Library</sdk:name-display>
  ```
- Just below you could find a direct download URL.

  ```
  <sdk:url>support_r19.1.zip</sdk:url>
  ```
- Now, it can be absolute path or relative path. In our case it is relative path. Just add the absolute current path before it. We are now on:

  ```
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/
  ```

  so, the link will be

  ```
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip
  ```
- If you don't find desired files, just try another repository

Note, that in mainland China `https://dl.google.com` may be blocked. You will to find a solution to this problem yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
    }
}
```

in my project level gradle file. Added this and it worked like charm.