# How to set proxy for android sdk manager?

Tags: android, proxy

I am behind a proxy and need to set up SDK manager for the android virtual device. But SDK manager is unable to download any os images/SDK updates from the add-on lists probably due to the proxy configuration. The solutions that I have already tried:

- Setting proxy port and host in android config file, or directly in SDK manager
- Creating a squid proxy server and make SDK manager connect to squid server
- Run android.bat as an administrator with proxy settings, username and password in command line

None of this worked and I still do not see the SDK updates or the OS images in the SDK manager. If anyone has some solutions for a similar problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Command Line syntax to use proxy settings

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose --no_https --proxy=http --proxy_host=<proxy_host> --proxy_port=<proxy_port>
```

Comment: How to send authentication to the proxy 
username and password?

Comment: I don't see an argument to pass the proxy username & password. See if you get a prompt for user name & password while executing. Raise an issue in github project https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/internal/AndroidCommand.groovy

Comment: thanks for you response it is not asking for authentication prompt

Comment: I also need to set authentication for my proxy

Comment: This gives me the same error mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 4):

> Installation of android SDK (**on windows 7 with proxy authetication**)
>   Command Line syntax to use proxy settings.

1. Edit `%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat`.

   Add **`-Dhttp.proxyUsername="MyUser" -Dhttp.proxyPassword="MyPass"`** on `"%JAVA_EXE%"`. I have something like this:

   ```html
   @rem Execute sdkmanager
   "%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyUsername="MyUser" -Dhttp.proxyPassword="MyPass" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
   ```
2. Install your packages for the Android SDK, just add **`--proxy=http --proxy_host=<proxy_host> --proxy_port=<proxy_port>`**. I have something like this:

```html
"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "emulator" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;27.0.3" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository" --proxy=http --proxy_host=pftwbappp04-wcg.mycompany.com.pe --proxy_port=8080
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this for GitLab CI ?

Comment: On Gitlab you would use sed or the alternative for windows instead to change the file:

https://github.com/game-ci/documentation/issues/405

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set it in settings

Goto

> Settings->Appearance and Behaviour->System settings-> HTTP Proxy

**Also note that some of Antivirus and Firewall may block your connection**
[image]