# Android Studio Platform Tools-can not download for api 24/28

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded android command line tools and now want to download platform tools for api-24 using this command

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

But i am not able to do so.

Error on the console is

```
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...

Warning: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...

Warning: File C:\..\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...
[=                                      ] 3% Computing updates...
[===                                    ] 8% Computing updates...
[===                                    ] 8% Computing updates...
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...

Warning: Failed to find package platform-tools
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...
```

Note :I am working behind corporate proxy

Comment: Have you configured the proxy in your SDK manager? If not check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296708/how-to-set-proxy-for-android-sdk-manager)

Answer (score 0):

you can download latest [Platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools) version and copy it to platform-tools folder in sdk folder