# Use GluonFX mobile behind a corporate proxy

Tags: java, maven, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I'm trying to build the GluonFX example project "HelloFX" as mentioned here: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android under section 5.4.4.

The main problem is, my computer runs behind a corporate proxy and however the gluonfx build script does not use the system proxy, because after downloading all maven dependencies the build fails.

The command I'm using is `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:compile`.

Output:

```
julian@debian:~/Downloads/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX$ mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.gluonhq.samples:hellofx >---------------------
[INFO] Building HelloFX 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) > process-classes @ hellofx >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ hellofx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) < process-classes @ hellofx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) @ hellofx ---
März 14, 2023 2:58:46 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: Substrate is tested with the Gluon's GraalVM build which you can find at https://github.com/gluonhq/graal/releases.
While you can still use other GraalVM builds, there is no guarantee that these will work properly with Substrate
März 14, 2023 2:58:46 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: ANDROID_SDK not found and will be downloaded.
März 14, 2023 2:58:46 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: ANDROID_NDK not found and will be downloaded.
März 14, 2023 2:58:46 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: sysroot path not found and will be downloaded.
März 14, 2023 2:58:46 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: Downloading Java Static Libs...
März 14, 2023 2:58:47 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logSevere
SCHWERWIEGEND: Downloading failed: download2.gluonhq.com
Check the log files under null
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error downloading zips: Error: /home/julian/.gluon/substrate/staticjdk-android-aarch64-gvm-18-ea+prep18-8.zip does not exist
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.setupDependencies(FileDeps.java:350)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.resolvePath(FileDeps.java:181)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.getAndroidSDKPath(FileDeps.java:125)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AndroidTargetConfiguration.<init>(AndroidTargetConfiguration.java:101)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.getTargetConfiguration(SubstrateDispatcher.java:402)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.<init>(SubstrateDispatcher.java:387)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBaseMojo.createSubstrateDispatcher(NativeBaseMojo.java:159)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo.execute(NativeCompileMojo.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.129 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-14T14:58:47+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: Error downloading zips: Error: /home/julian/.gluon/substrate/staticjdk-android-aarch64-gvm-18-ea+prep18-8.zip does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The proxy is configured in settings.xml as well as in the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY.
I'm running Debian in a VM on Windows 10 and I'm using CNTLM to provide proxy authentification.

Java Version 17
GraalVM Version 17
Debian 11.6

How can i configure a proxy for the GluonFX Maven Plugin?

---

EDIT:
I solved the first problem by using the options -Dhttp.proxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort

Now the next problem regarding the network connection occurs whilst fetching the Android toolchains:

```
INFORMATION: Downloading Android toolchain. It may take several minutes depending on your bandwidth.
März 16, 2023 2:15:58 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logSevere
SCHWERWIEGEND: Process sdkmanager failed with result: 1
Check the log files under null
And please check https://docs.gluonhq.com/ for more information.
März 16, 2023 2:15:58 PM com.gluonhq.substrate.util.Logger logInfo
INFORMATION: Logging process [sdkmanager] to file: /home/julian/Downloads/gluon-samples-master/HelloFX/target/gluonfx/log/process-sdkmanager-1678972558372.log
..
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error downloading zips: Could not run the Android sdk manager
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.setupDependencies(FileDeps.java:350)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.resolvePath(FileDeps.java:181)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.util.FileDeps.getAndroidNDKPath(FileDeps.java:136)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.target.AndroidTargetConfiguration.<init>(AndroidTargetConfiguration.java:102)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.getTargetConfiguration(SubstrateDispatcher.java:402)
    at com.gluonhq.substrate.SubstrateDispatcher.<init>(SubstrateDispatcher.java:387)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeBaseMojo.createSubstrateDispatcher(NativeBaseMojo.java:159)
    at com.gluonhq.NativeCompileMojo.execute(NativeCompileMojo.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.067 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-16T14:15:58+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:compile (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error: Error downloading zips: Could not run the Android sdk manager -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.746 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-16T14:15:58+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.gluonhq:gluonfx-maven-plugin:1.0.16:build (default-cli) on project hellofx: Error, gluonfx:build failed -> [Help 1]
```

The log file:

```
Process
=======
sdkmanager

Command Line
============
/home/julian/Downloads/graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/bin/java -Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=/home/julian/.gluon/substrate/Android/tools --illegal-access=permit -classpath /home/julian/.gluon/substrate/Android/tools/lib/*:/home/julian/.gluon/substrate/Android/tools/lib/java11/* com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli platforms;android-31 build-tools;31.0.0 platform-tools extras;android;m2repository extras;google;m2repository ndk-bundle

Output
======
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option --illegal-access=permit; support was removed in 17.0
Loading package information...                                                  
Loading local repository...                                                     
[                                       ] 3% Loading local repository...        
[                                       ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[                                       ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
[                                       ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: Failed to connect to host: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: File /home/julian/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
                                                                                
Warning: java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com
[=                                      ] 3% Fetch remote repository...         
[=                                      ] 3% Computing updates...               
[===                                    ] 8% Computing updates...               
[===                                    ] 8% Computing updates...               
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              
                                                                                
Warning: Failed to find package platforms;android-31
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...              


Result
======
```

Comment: Have you tried using command line options, like: `mvn -Pandroid -Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> gluonfx:build...`?

Comment: This did only solve one problem, now the next one occured, I edited the main question and added the errors

Comment: Right, as you can see from the log, the java command line doesn't include the proxy options of the maven command line. You might want to try `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511851/3956070)?

Comment: This would maybe work, but unfortunately with the java options env variable set, gluon cannot determine the graalvm version, cause in the class InternalProjectConfiguration.java the method getGraalVMJavaVersion tries to read the version in the first line of the output of the command "java -version". But the first line is now "Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: ..."

Comment: Even if i try to execute the command mentioned in the log file with the proxy options added, it fails, maybe the SdkManagerCli needs some additional proxy configuration

Comment: Obviously the android sdk manager needs the proxy configured manually: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296708/how-to-set-proxy-for-android-sdk-manager
But using thiy way, i need to execute the command by hand