# Unable to set proxy for Android SDK Manager on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, proxy

I have switched to Ubuntu 12.10 from windows and i am having trouble downloading android sdks through sdk manager, when ever i try to open sdk manager i get

Failed to fetch URL, reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
Failed to fetch URL, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com
error.....

i have searched for answers on stackoverflow as well but none helped me with the solution,

found a question in which he said i need to set sdk managers proxy but i am unable to see those options on my sdk manager.. like options->Settings
i followed this question [Android SDK and AVD Manager where is Settings menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195264/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-where-is-settings-menu/2204065#2204065)

*Please note i am under a proxy

any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: please Take a look at the folloing [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3810062/1292203)

Comment: well, i have already set proxy under Window" -> "Preferences" -> "General" -> "Network Connections" but i am getting the same error

Comment: also cannot see these Options on sdk manager to set proxy 
    -Click Settings - Will be asked for a proxy.
    -If have one enter the IP address and the port number. If not turn off your firewall.
    -Check "Force https://... " (to force SDK Manager to use http, not https)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this issue was resolved by editing androidtools.cgf file with proxy and port. i.e

```
sdkman.force.http=true
http.proxyPort=(port here)
http.proxyHost=(ip here)
```

this file can be found under .android folder from home folder

Comment: to access the file: sudo nano ~/.android/androidtool.cfg
and edit file as:
### Settings for Android Tool
#Thu Jul 04 16:36:07 PKT 2013
http.proxyPort=8090
sdkman.monitor.density=96
http.proxyHost=192.168.0.1
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.show.update.only=true
sdkman.use.dl.cache=true
sdkman.force.http=true

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
There is no androidtools.cfg under my home folder/.android.
I manually added one with the proxy, SDK manager still can't fetch the URL.

[Update]
The file name is "androidtool.cfg" and after setting proxy there, it works for me.