# Android SDK log shows: "Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused",what can be done?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, installation

When I try to download the Android API the Android SDK Manager log shows

```
"Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl-ssl.google.com refused"
```

This is not allowing the repository to be added. I verified the proxy settings under Network settings . How do I add the repository..whats the problem?

[image: Problem Image]

Comment: Are your date/time settings correct?

Comment: yes 5:17 pm 20th august..its correct..

Comment: Try opening SDK Setup manually (not from Eclipse) and opening Settings there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195264/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-where-is-settings-menu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be because you are connected to internet via a proxy server. So if so, you should set the proxy settings. Go to Tools>Options of the Android SDK Manager and set Http poxy server and Http Proxy Port.
eg:

- Http poxy server:cache.mrt.ac.lk
- Http Proxy Port:3128

  Restart SDK manager and try again.

Answer (score 5):

I also had a intruption when i try to unstall or update package in my SDK manager

> Downloading Google USB Driver,  revision 9 Download interrupted: 
>   Invalid argument: connect   Done. Nothing was installed.

I resolved it by doing this :

In SDK Manager go to  **Tools** => **Options** and ckeck the **" forces https//... sources to be fetched using http://... "**
as you can see in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the proxy problem.you should make the proxy settings blank.

- Tools>Options(SDK Manager)
- General>Network Connection(Preference)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this problem, going to **Tools -> Options -> Clear cache** solves it for me.