# Unable to install "Android SDK Platform Tools" from SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk, appium

Below error displays during installation:

```
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 26.0.2
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 26.0.2
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 98832431e339c82be1fe910a733a3782071200fd, got aa3ef6f18eff4b8f12dbdf980647a6ce6c2ebe8c.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Comment: I have the very same problem. Tried turning off anti-virus, Windows Firewall, clearing SDK Manager cache, forcing HTTP and none of the above worked.

Comment: Did you check if it's a proxy issue? Check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330043/android-sdk-log-shows-download-interrupted-connection-to-https-dl-ssl-googl).

Answer (score 26):

I had to install it by myself.

1. Download link:
   https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html
2. Select the zip file `SDK Platform-Tools for Windows` and extract it.
3. Move it into your android directory, in my case it was:     `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2433_19.0.27659.1188`.
4. Now you have the new directory: `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidSDK-2433_19.0.27659.1188\platform-tools`.
5. Run `SDK Manager.exe` again.

In my case, the error was gone. I had to install 4 packages first and then I had to install 3 packages after that. Now it run perfect.

Comment: This work around worked for me. My guess is Google just goofed calculating the checksum for their zip.

Comment: Direct download link for this case could be: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip. Of course this may not remain like this.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks. It might not be the best answer but it's all we've got. Only Google can make this right.

Comment: On Win7 pro x64 with VS 2017 my Android SDK folder was C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

Comment: This worked for me as well.  In my case, on **Windows 10**, Android  SDK folder is - "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

Answer (score 8):

You can just extract the archive the SDK Manager already downloaded:

1. Go to your android-sdk directory
2. Enter the 'temp' folder
3. Extract the 'platform-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip' to the android-sdk root directory

But this makes the checksum pointless, it might be better to wait until it is fixed unless you need the new version now.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by first removing the Android SDK Platform-tools using the Android SDK Manager. Then I used the direct download link provided by Umair Malhi above (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r26.0.2-windows.zip) then extracted the platform-tools folder into the SDK folder (which in my case is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25). If you rerun Android SDK Manager, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, after running Visual Studio as an Administrator then the updates went through successfully.

EDIT: Newer versions of VS now prompts you to run VS in Administrator mode when you click on Android SDK Platform Tools.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same checksum issue, until I just updated to Android Studio 3.0. Now the Android SDK Platform-tools 26.0.2 downloads and installs as expected. Not sure if the issue still exists for Android Studio 2.x or it was fixed separately, but it's worth trying again now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I needed to do was run Android Studio as administrator and the the packages installed with no problem.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, in my case I hadn't write rules to `platform-tools` folder. So I gave me write rules with the command:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw
```