# Sdk platform 26.0.2 not installing

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk

I got an error like this:

```
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 26.0.2
Download finished with wrong checksum. Expected 685bb47f28db4c739b1815be3155af1974929ea6, got 161ca26461d4caec6cbbef513891fcd04a4fcf52.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

Comment: *Download finished with wrong checksum.* This site is about programming issues. You better ask this on [Super User.](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Re-install sdk platform

Comment: Re-install sdk platform :i tried same error showing

Comment: see my sdk manger :https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZANmV7ZqEmNqW5ijhbHMcDT0lKULQhMpqhk

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46998252/unable-to-install-android-sdk-platform-tools-from-sdk-manager